# Excel 2016 VBA workbook activates but then deactivates

Tags: excel, combobox, userform, vba

I have a weird situation that I haven't been able to find the solution for.

I am dealing with large amounts of data on multiple workbooks that need to be opened (let's say 3 workbooks).  I need a Userform to be able to interact with all 3 workbooks.

I have made a ComboBox able to do that by when the userform is initialized, it will add the names of the workbooks to the Combobox:

```
'* initialize the userform *'
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    '* get the name of all the workbooks and add to the combobox '*
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        Me.PrimaryBook_ComboBox.AddItem wb.name
    Next wb

    Me.PrimaryBook_ComboBox = ActiveWorkbook.name
End Sub
```

Upon a change, it will activate that workbook:

```
Private Sub PrimaryBook_ComboBox_Change()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Dim wb As Workbook
    If Me.PrimaryBook_ComboBox <> "" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks(Me.PrimaryBook_ComboBox.Text)
        wb.Activate
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

(this userform has two refedits in it)

When I select another workbook in the combobox, it brings that workbook to the front as it should.  But immediately as I click into one of my RefEdit boxes, it goes back to the original workbook opened first.

Here's another part I don't understand, when I load this in Excel 2010 it's flawless. I can select which workbook I want and click on the RefEdit and that workbook will remain activated.

Is there something I'm missing?  Any tips and/or tricks that I did not think of?

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't Application.ScreenUpdating be set as False then True? You have it the other way around

Comment: I turn it off in my macro that calls the form, when the form is unloaded I turn it back on. But I need to turn it  on when activating a workbook so it gets shown to the front. Then I turn it back off immediately (as shown)

Comment: @RADO update: it seems that whichever workbook is active (opened in front) is the one that the userform is tied to.  If I have book 3 in front and run the userform, when I change the book to, say, book2 it will activate it but then as soon as I click somewhere else on the userform it goes directly back to book 3.

Answer (score 0):

[delete , posted solution did not fix problem]